# How to retrieve actual secret key from KeyStore in java?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, keystore, secret-key

I'm not well aware with Java KeyStore. What I want to do is to have an encrypted structure to store my keys.

I've multiple clusters and there exists a key associated with every cluster & now I want to store those keys securely such that they are all encrypted using single main key (for an instance, 'loginid')

I wandered alot in search of this issue and somewhere on stackoverflow itself someone suggested about Java keyStore to store SecretKey (Symmetric Encryption). I read its documentation & found it perfect as per my requirements but couldn't understand its implementation properly.

Here is a code snippet I'm working on -

```
public class Prac {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, UnrecoverableEntryException {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");        
        char[] ksPwd = "yashkaranje98".toCharArray();        
        ks.load(null, ksPwd);        
        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(ksPwd);

        javax.crypto.SecretKey mySecretKey = new SecretKeySpec("_anky!@ubn#$0e41".getBytes(),"AES");
        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(mySecretKey);
        ks.setEntry("cluster1", skEntry, protParam);

        java.io.FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream("keystore.ks");
            ks.store(fos, ksPwd);
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        }

        java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
          ks.load(new FileInputStream("keystore.ks"), ksPwd);
        } finally {
                if (fis != null) {
                        fis.close();
                }
        }


        SecretKey key = (SecretKey)ks.getKey("cluster1", ksPwd);
        String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded());
        System.out.println(encodedKey);  

    }
}
```

> Alias: "cluster1"
>
> Key to store: _anky!@ubn#$0e41
>
> Protection Parameter: yashkaranje98
>
> > It prints: X2Fua3khQHVibiMkMGU0MQ==
> >
> > What I expect is key itsef: _anky!@ubn#$0e41

Kindly please let me know what I'm missing...but before please tell me what I'm expecting is it even legit? or does it make sense?

(I am still learning about this KeyStore concept so there might be some silly mistakes.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. In the last two lines you obviously encode the key to base64 code and print it but then you wonder why it prints a base64 encoded result?

Comment: Thanks for your attention @jps; kindly plz look at the problem again as I've made some changes there. As an output,  we get byte stream of secret key -> we encode it to base64 format so that it can be printed in String form, right? But what I'm expecting is the actual key itself (_anky!@ubn#$0e41), not the AES encoded one (X2Fua3khQHVibiMkMGU0MQ==). Well, I'm not sure what I'm asking is it even correct or not but please make me aware of it if I've mistake somewhere. Thanks again!

Comment: What you are expecting to see is obviously not the result of base64-encoding. So why are you base64-encoding?

Comment: @YashK You're effectively asking *"Why does this data that I'm base64 encoding look like it has been base64 encoded?"*

Comment: `X2Fua3khQHVibiMkMGU0MQ==` is not AES encoded as you say in your comment but base64 encoded and can easily be decoded with any base64 decoder (e.g. https://www.base64decode.org/) into the desired `_anky!@ubn#$0e41`. As mentioned before, in the last two lines you're encoding it into base64, so why you do this if you don't want it?

Comment: Thanks alot @user207421, @Luke Joshua Park & especially @jps; I got the desired result after decoding that base64 encoded string. Now what I had in my mind previously was something else. I knew that `SecretKey key` is the actual key but I couldn't print it as I expected. I tried `SysOut` & `@override toString()` but nothing worked and that's why I got confused. Kindly please tell me how to extract that actual key out of object with no need of encodng as it's unnecessary like you all mentioned.

Comment: Thanks again @jps; Now I understand where I mistaken.

Comment: You already had the desired result. You didn't need to decode it, because you didn't need to encode it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

A secret AES key consists of random bytes. Such a key should *not* be printed directly, because the bytes may not represent valid characters or they may present control characters that don't print on screen. If you'd copy them then you might miss data. If you print them in the wrong terminal you may send terminal control codes.

Because of this you *need* to print out key values as hexadecimals or base 64. Normally for symmetric keys hex is preferred as it is easy to see the contents *and size* from the hex (the size in bytes is half that of the hex size, the size in bits is 4 times the hex size as each hex digit represents a 4 bit nibble). However, as Java still lacks a good Hex encoder, base 64 is also a good option.

Of course, in that case, to compare, you should also decode it from base 64 before you insert it into the key store.

---

Also beware that you don't specify the character encoding when you call `getBytes` on the string. If you would use higher valued characters then you may get different results on various systems, as `getBytes` without argument assumes the platform encoding. Specifying `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` usually makes more sense.

Of course, as keys should contain random bytes, the `getBytes` method needs to go entirely, but you should keep this in mind anyway.

---

When I look at the code it seems you've missed the last 10 years of Java progress. No `var`, no `null` avoidance, missing imports, and no try-with-resources. That's a shame, because those would make your code a lot more readable. It's valid, mind you, but yeah...

Comment: Your first para concludes _Need of encoding? then decoding again to get the actual secret key_ and of course _Why can't we retrieve out skey from raw byte stream without undergoing the encoding process?_ I'm grateful to you too.

Earlier I thought no need to upload whole code cuz I already emphasized on the necessary part of code where there is need to pay attention and that's why other things like you mentioned I omitted. I've taken care of all those things in my actual use. I'll take care of what you suggested from now on. Thanks for that!